# Javascript - Concat a string and int not working (Lightswitch HTML)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

scenario: I have a data item which I want to display the total of a value. and this is done with the following code:

```
var int1 = 5;
var int2 = 6;
var int3 = 7;
var total = parseFloat(int1) + parseFloat(int2) + parseFloat(int3);
//total = 18.00;
```

Now this displays as 18 on the screen where I want it to appear however I am having difficulty in adding a **£** symbol to the equation. I've tried the following with little success:

```
var displayTotal = "£" + total  //returns NaN

var symbol = "£";
var changeToString = total.toString();
var displayTotal = symbol.concat(changeToString); //retuns NaN
```

this isn't that difficult so im missing something obvious so hopefully I can get the help I need here. and to clarify I want to be able to display my Total with a £ sign in front, i.e. £18.00

thanks for any help

Comment: change this "var displayTotal = symbol.concat(changeToString);" to ' "£" + total '. Bcoz now both are strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "\u00A3" code for the pound symbol. It should look like example below:

```
var displayTotal = "\u00A3" + total;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the ff. code below.

```
var int1 = 5;
var int2 = 6;
var int3 = 7;
var total = parseFloat(int1) + parseFloat(int2) + parseFloat(int3);
var displayTotal = String.fromCharCode('163') + total  //returns NaN
            console.log(displayTotal);
            alert(displayTotal);
```

The fromCharCode() method converts Unicode values into characters.

to check for other character codes:

```
for(x=0;x<300;x++){
console.log("Char Code:"+x+" "+"Symbol:"+String.fromCharCode(x));
}
```

you can also use it like this

```
console.log(String.fromCharCode(83,84,65,67,75));
```